# react navigation bottom nav shows a grey box on focus input

Tags: coding-style, react-native, react-navigation

I have a problem with bottom nav when I focus on a input

[image: how i can solve that ?]

When I focus on that input field bottom nav be hide but that grey box is before it.

I wanna know how I can delete that box

```js
const TabBarComponent = props => <BottomTabBar {...props} />;

  {
    initialRouteName: "showFlow",
    tabBarComponent: props => (
      <TabBarComponent {...props} style={styles.bottomNav} />
    ),
    tabBarOptions: {
      inactiveTintColor: colors.grey,
      activeTintColor: colors.background1
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `keyboardHidesTabBar` from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator#tabbaroptions to `false`.

Comment: ty for answer to this question. i want to hide that when i focusing on a input.

Answer (score 0):

finally i did find a way for solve that problem:

```
import { Keyboard } from "react-native";
const TabBarComponent = props => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      let keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
        "keyboardDidShow",
        _keyboardDidShow
      );

      let keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
        "keyboardDidHide",
        _keyboardDidHide
      );

      return () => {
        keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
      };
    }, []);

  const _keyboardDidHide = () => setShow(false);
  const _keyboardDidShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <BottomTabBar
      {...props}
      style={{ height: show ? 0 : 80, backgroundColor: colors.background1 }}
    />
  );
};
```